# Generar PDF con IText7

Tags: pdf, .net-core, itext

es posible generar otro pdf a partir de una plantilla PDF en otra solo cambiando valores con `itext7` estoy en `C#` es decir tengo un PDF

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, `[name]` adipiscing elit. Curabitur mollis, tellus dignissim 
bibendum convallis, `[name]` erat ullamcorper urna, in elementum ex mauris a ligula. Sed vitae
leo at enim feugiat sagittis sed nec `[year]`. Nam ut lobortis dui. Suspendisse mauris mauris,
aliquet tempus nisl nec, volutpat ullamcorper elit. Nam tincidunt tincidunt odio eget vehicula. Donec porta euismod diam in `[year]`. Donec lobortis lacinia tortor at accumsan. Sed commodo ante quis est auctor, ut ultrices tellus vestibulum. Maecenas maximus, risusdapibus blandit volutpat, `[year]`lorem mattis dolor, non venenatis dui neque quis dolor. 
Vivamus sit amet lectus scelerisque, sollicitudin nunc quis, `[ocupation]`ante. Vestibulum ut 
arcu nec felis vulputate sollicitudin id vitae magna. Vivamus sodales lobortis elit, vitae 
mattis risus convallis at.
```

intenté seguir la documentacion con formularios, pero hace eso mismo, se crea un formulario en el PDF plantilla, lo que quiero es reemplazar los valores en corchete, o llaves, lo que sea para declarar variable dentro del PDF plantilla

```
        public void ManipulatePdf(String src , String dest) {
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));

            PdfFormField personal = new NonTerminalFormFieldBuilder(pdfDoc, "name")
                .CreateNonTerminalFormField();
            PdfTextFormField name = new TextFormFieldBuilder(pdfDoc, "year")
                .SetWidgetRectangle(new Rectangle(36, 760, 108, 30)).CreateText();
            name.SetValue("");
            personal.AddKid(name);
            PdfTextFormField password = new TextFormFieldBuilder(pdfDoc, "ocupation")
                .SetWidgetRectangle(new Rectangle(150, 760, 300, 30)).CreateText();
            password.SetValue("");
            personal.AddKid(password);
            PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).AddField(personal, pdfDoc.GetFirstPage());

            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
```